# When using resx files, can you have variables replacing with constant values

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resx

We're working on an application that will probably change its name. What I'd like to do is have a row defined as `ProductName` = `'Temp Product Name'` and then in other resources, something like `Welcome` = `'Welcome to {ProductName}'` and have the value from another row applied.

Is this possible? I know there is always find and replace, however I'd like to use variables for other uses in resource files.

Comment: Have not heard of something like that. Maybe SmartFormat provides something in this direction, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating your own resource manager. Perhaps its more effort than you want to undertake, but it is guaranteed to meet your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx